# Can Two Or More ATTinys Share One External Crystal?

Tags: embedded, oscillator, clock, attiny, crystal

I've got two I2C Slave ATTiny85 chips both running at 16MHz with external crystals. Can they both share a single crystal with the 22pf caps? Is there anything wrong with this?

I don't have any free pins on the ATTinys to route a clock signal out of one ATTiny into another.

If there's some type of external clock circuit, how is that constructed and connected/shared with both ATTinys.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f16QGt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>